# Loop for a variable in PHP

Tags: php

I have column named as `r1_name`, `r2_name`, `r3_name` in my table and .... I want to iterate them using `for` loop.

```
for($r=1; $r<=5; $r++) {  
    echo $data->r[$r]_name;// how am i going to iterate this
}
```

I get an error of:

```
syntax error, unexpected '_name'
```

Comment: why you wont use `while ($results[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) continue;`?

Comment: @Smash: Where does the OP mention that he's fetching the data from a database? (In any case, you certainly don't want to use `mysql_*` functions. They're **officially deprecated**.)

Comment: btw there is a foreach loop as well you can do.

Comment: @AmalMurali I know that they're deprecated, that's why I did the question in my answer, but removed it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use curly brace syntax:

```
for($r=1; $r<=5; $r++) {  
    echo $data->{"r{$r}_name"};
}
```

Or concatenation:

```
for($r=1; $r<=5; $r++) {  
    echo $data->{'r' . $r . '_name'};
}
```